# How to add custom framework in a project?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I am making an app in which I am using BMSocialShare.framework for Facebook sharing. I have add this framework in my project by this step - Add File to `"My_project"  -> select framework -> add.` But when I deploy this project in another system them I have got this framework 
missing and got this type of warning -

**warning: Could not find object file**

> "/Users/vinzenzweber/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BMSocialShare-gedvbinixmfywidbwutkdxrdvdzo/Build/Intermediates/BMSocialShare.build/Release-iphonesimulator/BMSocialShareFramework.build/Objects-normal/i386/BMSocialShare.o"
>   - no debug information available for "/Users/vinzenzweber/Documents/xcodeworkspace/blockhaus-git/BMSocialShare/iOS/BMSocialShare/BMSocialShare/BMSocialShare.m".

and app get crashed. So can you suggest me that what is the proper way to add an framework if framework is not present in our existing list.

Comment: you always need to create a sub folder in your project your project main folder and name as Frameworks and add all Frameworks to that

Comment: Did you check "Copy items into destination group's folder" option when you were adding

Answer (score 5):

You can follow below steps:

1. Create sub-folder in your project and add framework into that folder.
2. Now, open Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. And click on '+' button.
3. Then click on "Add Other" instead of adding default framework.

Now, you have added framework successfully.